How can I change app_url of Perl Kelp App
I want to change app_url.
I did it as follows:
package Post;
use Kelp::Base 'Kelp';

use utf8;

sub before_dispatch {
    # overriding this method disables access logs
}

sub build {
    my $self = shift;
    
    $self->config_hash->{app_url}='https://perl-kelp.sys5.co';

It seems to work.
Is this a good way?
